# How to create multiple level menu bar where each level should have overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have created a menu which has two levels. I am trying to create scroll for both scroll for both levels (first and second) along with mouse hover for second.

As I fix the height of first level menu using the overflow, mouse hover functionality doesn't work and it doesn't show up the second level on mouse hover instead it keeps everything inside the first level.

Please check below screenshot

http://screencast.com/t/hpYU3Y51

FYI, I am using WordPress platform for this website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. This is how I resolved the problem with blogs list menu on admin for MU (Multi Site) Wordpress. MU Wordpress has multiple blogs integrated under one wordpress, so when this blogs list gets big, all blogs can't be seen and some are left out and can't be reached nor seen nor clicked. This fix adds a scroll bar, when the list exceeds certain number of blogs:

So, in  wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css:
-Add this:

```
#wp-admin-bar-my-sites-list
{ max-height: 520px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Try to apply this CSS to your own menu that you want to set the scrollbar to.